# Navigation mesh and graph

Tags: c++, graph, sfml, mesh

I'm working on a project SFML/C++, and I need to use a navigation mesh for a polygon edge movement . A little bit like this :

[image: Blank areas are non walkable zone]

Here the path uses both the edge centers and vertices.

I tried to do a navmesh with a 2D constrained triangulations but I had some troubles to apply the algorithm.

I need a library,  written in C++ to handle these drawing. Is there any library that meets my requirement?

Thank you in advance